# How to export polyline layer from Yandex Maps

Tags: qgis, export, line, yandex

I am interested in exporting a polyline layer(s) of Moscow bike routes from Yandex maps.  The layer does not belong to me but it is open to public use.  I would prefer a KML, but just getting the coordinates in usable shape would be great.  The coordinates seem to be embedded in the source code but I don't know to reshape that easily into a list of coordinates in .csv format  which can then be mapped in QGIS.

https://maps.yandex.ru/213/moscow/?z=11&ll=37.500488%2C55.732220&l=map&origin=jsapi_2_1_34&from=api-maps&um=constructor%3AZ4zDPV2057F7o6aqu4WkQXKpLoiHO9i2

Comment: @Mapperz Thank's, and how to obtain coordinates from the source (Yandex)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the coordinates from the source:

- copy & paste into notepad++
- make into columns (replace [ with /n)
- remove ], with none. load x,y into qgis (create layer from a
  delimited text file)
- create a point file
- use point2one plugin to create lines
- repeat for the other coordinates

[image]